# Assert lists have the same objects with hamcrest fails

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have two lists and I want to verify that they have the same objects in the same order. For this reason I am using hamcrest but for some reason I do not understand I get a compile error:

Can someone explain the error and how I can fix it ?

```
List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("asd", "bc", "qwe");
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("asd", "bc", "qwe");

assertThat(actual,IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder(expected));
```

This is the error message:

```
com.me.Test.java:[160,1] no suitable method found for 
assertThat(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? 
extends java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>)
method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>) is not applicable
(no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type
org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.util.List<java.lang.String>>> conforms to formal parameter type org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>)
method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<T>) is not applicable
(cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: Please, post the compile error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [javadoc of `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.html#containsInAnyOrder%28T...%29). Assuming, you're not trying to pass `Matcher` to this method, you should pass an array (or varargs) to this method, for example:

```
assertThat(actual, IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder("qwe", "asd", "bc"));
```

or

```
assertThat(actual,IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray(new String[expected.size()])));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a Set, or sort the arrays first.

```
Collectons.sort(actual); 
Collections.sort(expected); // if not sorted already.
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

or in Java 8

```
actual.sort();
expected.sort();
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

or if duplicates can be ignored

```
assertEquals(new HashSet<>(expected), new HashSet<>(actual));
```